# Why is my standard output not what was expected in REVEL?

Tags: python-3.x

I keep getting the "Your standard output is not what was expected." error even though it is almost identical to the example.

My assumption is that it's because the decimals are not matching...

Here is my code:

```
a1=float(input("Enter the real part of the first complex number: "))
a2=float(input("Enter the imaginary part of the first complex number: "))
b1=float(input("Enter the real part of the second complex number: "))
b2=float(input("Enter the imaginary part of the second complex number: "))
a=complex(a1,a2)
b=complex(b1,b2)
strA=str(a).replace('j','i')
strB=str(b).replace('j','i')
print(" %s + %s = %s"%(strA,strB,str(a+b).replace('j','i')))
print(" %s - %s = %s"%(strA,strB,str(a-b).replace('j','i')))
print(" %s * %s = %s"%(strA,strB,str(a*b).replace('j','i')))
print(" %s / %s = %s"%(strA,strB,str(a/b).replace('j','i')))
print("|%s|= %f"%(strA,abs(a)))
```

Here is my output:

```
Enter the real part of the first complex number: 3.5
Enter the imaginary part of the first complex number: 6.5
Enter the real part of the second complex number: -3.5
Enter the imaginary part of the second complex number: 1
 (3.5+6.5i) + (-3.5+1i) = 7.5i
 (3.5+6.5i) - (-3.5+1i) = (7+5.5i)
 (3.5+6.5i) * (-3.5+1i) = (-18.75-19.25i)
 (3.5+6.5i) / (-3.5+1i) = (-0.43396226415094347-1.9811320754716981i)
|(3.5+6.5i)|= 7.382412
```

And this is the output I'm supposed to get:

```
Enter the real part of the first complex number: 3.5
Enter the imaginary part of the first complex number: 6.5
Enter the real part of the second complex number: -3.5
Enter the imaginary part of the second complex number: 1
(3.5 + 6.5i) + (-3.5 + 1i) = (0.0 + 7.5i)
(3.5 + 6.5i) - (-3.5 + 1i) = (7.0 + 5.5i)
(3.5 + 6.5i) * (-3.5 + 1i) = (-18.75 - 19.25i)
(3.5 + 6.5i) / (-3.5 + 1i) = (-0.43396226415 - 1.98113207547i)
|(3.5 + 6.5i)| = 7.3824115301167
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Checking output 
Your standard output is not what was expected.
```

Please help me to fix this error!

Comment: It looks like you have extra spaces at the start of your results. Maybe try trim?

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, but thanks!